# PowerEnumerate PInvoke resizes array

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, power-management

I'm trying to write a C# program that enumerates Windows power management schemes by calling [PowerEnumerate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372730(v=vs.85).aspx), but after debugging the following code, I notice that the length of `buffer` is `1`.

```
uint length = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
Guid id = Guid.Empty;
PowerEnumerate(IntPtr.Zero, ref id, ref id, 16, 0, ref buffer, ref length);
buffer = new byte[length];
PowerEnumerate(IntPtr.Zero, ref id, ref id, 16, 0, ref buffer, ref bufferSize);
```

`PowerEnumerate` is declared as follows:

```
[DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
public static extern UInt32 PowerEnumerate
(
    IntPtr RootPowerKey, 
    ref Guid SchemeGuid, 
    ref Guid SubGroupOfPowerSettingsGuid, 
    PowerDataAccessor AccessFlags,
    UInt32 Index, 
    ref Byte[] Buffer, 
    ref UInt32 BufferSize
);
```

`PowerEnumerate` is called twice. The first time for getting the required buffer length. The second time for actually reading into the buffer.

While debugging, I noticed that the first call to `PowerEnumerate` *(line 4)* sets `length` to `16` (which is weird because I have more than one power scheme in debugged environment, while one GUID is 16 bytes, but that is probably another story), and resizes `buffer` to 1 byte.

After instantiating `buffer` for the second time *(line 5)* with the length specified by the first call to `PowerEnumerate`, `buffer` is 16 bytes long. But the second call to `PowerEnumerate` *(line 6)* resizes `buffer` to 1 byte again.

I've read my code over and over, but I can't spot any mistakes, and my head is soon running out of hair!

Why don't I get the expected results from the above code? Is there something wrong with the declaration?

Comment: For the second problem (only receiving one GUID): `PowerEnumerate` retrieves only one item - the item specified by the `Index` parameter; a common approach is to use a `for` loop. Also, when enumerating power schemes (the `AccessFlags` parameter is `16`), the minimum buffer length is always 16 bytes, thus the first call to `PowerEnumerate` is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Buffer` parameter is declared incorrectly. A byte array is already a reference, and passing by `ref` makes it a double pointer. It should be:

```
byte[] Buffer
```

Pass `null` for the buffer parameter on the first call.

It also looks like you should be passing `NULL` for the GUIDs. You may need to declare those parameters as `IntPtr` and pass `IntPtr.Zero`.

It is also a terrible mistake to ignore the return value and so neglect error checking. You must address that immediately.

I'd use the following declaration:

```
[DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
public static extern uint PowerEnumerate
(
    IntPtr RootPowerKey,
    IntPtr SchemeGuid,
    IntPtr SubGroupOfPowerSettingsGuid,
    PowerDataAccessor AccessFlags,
    uint Index,
    byte[] Buffer,
    ref uint BufferSize
);
```

Comment: Damn, I never get those PInvocations right, and now I feel terrible for ignoring the return value. Anyway, this seems to work (although there's still only one GUID enumerated, but I'll look into that later). Thanks!